# How to use multiple 'Where' expressions and chain them together with AND and OR using C#/.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, expression-trees

I am trying to make a filtering system in my web app. The problem is I don't know how many filters will be requested from my client to API. I've build it so the array of the filters comes from a single string like this: `?sizeFilters=big,small,medium`

Then I use a `string[] names = sizeFilters.Split(',');` to get single expression like `Where(x => x.listOfSizes.contains(names[index]));`

I need also to make the chain of the expression using AND and OR because I am gonna use another filter for example: `'?typeFilters=normal,extra,spicy'`

So I need to make it that the whole expressions looks like this but it might be few times longer, it needs to work with different size of arrays:

return items `Where size is big OR small OR medium AND Where type is normal OR extra OR spicy`

```
Where(x => x.Sizes == "Small" || x => x.Sizes == "Medium" || x => x.Sizes == "Big" && 
x => x.Types == "normal" || x => x.Types == "extra" || x => x.Types == "Spicy")
```

Comment: Multiple `Where` clauses will function as AND automatically. `Where(z => somecondition).Where(z => anothercondition)`.

Comment: `Where size is big OR small OR medium AND Where type is normal OR extra OR spicy` You want `Where(x => listOfSizes.Contains(x.size)).Where(z => listOfTypes.Contains(x.type))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest option would be, as others have noted, to build your `OR`s using `Enumerable.Contains` within an expression; and to build your `AND`s by calling `Where` multiple times.

```cs
// using these values as an example
string[] sizeTerms = /* initialize */;
string[] typeTerms = /* initialize */;

IQueryable<Item> items = /* initialize */
if (sizeTerms.Any()) {
    items = items.Where(x => sizeTerms.Contains(x.Size));
}
if (typeTerms.Any()) {
    items = items.Where(x => typeTerms.Contains(x.Type));
}
```

If you want, you could wrap this logic into an extension method that takes an expression to filter against, and an `IEnumerable<string>` for the filter values; and constructs and applies the `Contains` method:

```cs
// using System.Reflection
// using static System.Linq.Expressions.Expression

private static MethodInfo containsMethod = typeof(List<>).GetMethod("Contains");

public static IQueryable<TElement> WhereValues<TElement, TFilterTarget>(
        this IQueryable<TElement> qry, 
        Expression<Func<TElement, TFilterTarget>> targetExpr, 
        IEnumerable<string> values
) {
    var lst = values.ToList();
    if (!lst.Any()) { return qry; }

    return qry.Where(
        Lambda<Expression<Func<TElement, bool>>>(
            Call(
                Constant(lst),
                containsMethod.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T)),
                targetExpr.Body
            ),
            targetExpr.Parameters.ToArray()
        )
    );
}
```

and can be called like this:

```cs
qry = qry
    .WhereValues(x => x.Size, sizeTerms)
    .WhereValues(x => x.Type, typeTerms);
```

One caveat: the query will be built based on the values passed into the method; if they are later changed, the query won't reflect those changes. If this is an issue:

- get the appropriate overload of `Enumerable.Contains`, instead of `List.Contains`, and
- use the overload of `Expression.Call` which produces a static method call, instead of an instance method call.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply call `.Where` multiple times to AND expressions together. Dynamically OR-ing expressions together is much more difficult. You'll need to rebuild the Expression graph to include the `OrElse` operator, and ensure that all expressions are based on the same `ParameterExpression`.

```cs
public class Replacer : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Expression, Expression> _replacements;

    public Replacer(IEnumerable<Expression> before, IEnumerable<Expression> after)
    {
        _replacements = new Dictionary<Expression, Expression>(before.Zip(after, (a, b) => KeyValuePair.Create(a, b)));
    }

    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        if (node != null && _replacements.TryGetValue(node, out var replace))
            return base.Visit(replace);
        return base.Visit(node);
    }
}

public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1, Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
{
    if (expr1 == null)
        return expr2;
    if (expr2 == null)
        return expr1;
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
        Expression.OrElse(
            expr1.Body,
            new Replacer(expr2.Parameters, expr1.Parameters).Visit(expr2.Body)
        ),
        expr1.Parameters);
}

public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1, Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
{
    if (expr1 == null)
        return expr2;
    if (expr2 == null)
        return expr1;
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
        Expression.AndAlso(
            expr1.Body,
            new Replacer(expr2.Parameters, expr1.Parameters).Visit(expr2.Body)
        ),
        expr1.Parameters);
}

// Usage
Expression<Func<TableObject, bool>> where = null;
if (...)
    where = where.Or(x => sizeFilters.Contains(x.Size));
if (...)
    where = where.Or(x => typeFilters.Contains(x.Type));
if (where!=null)
    query = query.Where(where);
```

Edit; Since this was written, EF Core now exposes `ReplacingExpressionVisitor` which can be used instead of the `Replacer` above.

Comment: Because the OP isn't starting from a `ParameterExpression`, but from a set of strings, I think this answer is more complex than needed. Use `Expression.Parameter` to create a single `ParameterExpression` of the appropriate type, use `Expression.Property` to create a member-access for each array, build each filter expression using `Expression.Equal`, aggregate together the single array's filter expression using `Expression.Or`, and aggregate the filter expressions for all the arrays using `Expression.And`. Wrap the whole thing in a strongly-typed lambda expression using `Expression.Lambda`.

Comment: My answer doesn't show how to build expressions from scratch, since that often leads to an inner platform with strange limitations. Instead I demonstrated how to write an extension method to merge existing expressions with either AND or OR operators. The OP may be able to solve their actual problem with multiple `.where(... .Contains() )` statements, but they did ask "chain ... expression using AND and OR".

Comment: _since that often leads to an inner platform with strange limitations_ Could you give an example of how that might happen here? The OP seems to be starting with a set of sets of string values; each inner set maps to an equality test on one property, and combined using OR; the resulting elements of the combined tests map into a single expression using AND. Isn't this requirement and implementation specific enough?

Comment: Requirements change. "Now I need to support OR-ing `x.A.B like '%foo%'` as well". If possible, let the C# compiler build expressions. Then tweak them to extend features, rather than replace them. Then you can use every feature that EF Core already supports.

Answer (score 0):

I think following should work

```
        var query = _context.Set<[Entity]>();
        if (sizeFilterPresent)
        {
            query = query.Where(r => sizes.Contains(r.Size));
        }

        if(typesFilterPresent)
        {
          query = query.Where(r => types.Contains(r.Type));
        }
        var results = query.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
var result = data.Where(p => sizeFilters.Contains(p.Size) && typeFilters.Contains(p.Type));
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it look neat, my advice would be to create and extension method. This way you can use it as any other LINQ method. See [extension methods demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

Assuming your source is an `IQuertyable<TSource>`.

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> WhereAnd<TSource>(
    this IQueryable<TSource> source,
    IEnumerable<Expression<Func<TSource,bool>>> filterPredicates)
{
    // TODO: handle null source, expressions;
    IQueryable<TSource> filteredSource = source;
    foreach (var predicate in filterPredicates)
    {
        filteredSource = filteredSource.Where(predicate);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var predicates = new List<Expression<Func<TSource,bool>>>()
{
    customer => customer.BirthDay.Year <= 1950,
    customer => customer.CityId == GetCityId("New York"),
    customer => customer.Gender == Gender.Male,
}

var oldNewYorkMaleCustomers = dbContext.Customers.WhereAnd(predicates).ToList();
```

Note: an empty collection of filterpredicates will filter by no predicate: you get the original data:

```
var emptyFilter = Queryable.Empty<Expression<Func<Customer, bool>>>();
var allCustomers = dbContext.Customers.WhereAnd(emptyFilter);
```