# How can i add different amount of expressions to Where statement using && and || in C#/.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I need to return something like this dynamicaly, it might have more than just sizes or types in future, for example:

```
Where((x => x.Sizes == "Small" || x => x.Sizes == "Medium" || x => x.Sizes == "Big") && 
(x => x.Types == "normal" || x => x.Types == "extra" || x => x.Types == "Spicy"))
```

from my list of Sizes and Types:

```
List<string> Sizes { "Small", "Medium", "Big", ...} 
List<string> Types { "Normal", "Extra", "Spicy", ...}
```

these lists might be bigger and there might be additional List added later on.

I've got my params i want to filter from my url like this `?types=normal,extra&sizes=big,small`.
`types` and `sizes` are `string` so i just split them with `.Split(',');` this way i get a `string[] sizes` and `string[] types`

These two arrays are dynamic sizes, there might be 0  or even 50 strings. I want to return all sizes that match the sizes in array i created.

So we are back to the start but i have to  do it using these two(or more) arrays and iterate through them.

```
database.table.Where(
(x => x.Sizes == sizes[0] || x => x.Sizes == sizes[1] || so on ...) 
&& 
(x => x.Types == types[0]|| x => x.Types == types[1] || so on...))
```

Comment: Note that `A || B || C && D || E || F` is equivalent to `A || B || (C && D) || E || F`

Comment: `database.table.Where(x=> sizes.Contains(x.Sizes))` and just extend that to also test for Types. This way its not relevant how many values are in the enumerables.

Comment: `var items = database.table.Where(x=> sizes.Contains(x.Sizes) && types.Contains(x.Types))`

Comment: You wouldn't write such code in SQL, you'd write `WHERE sizes in ('A','B','C')`. The equivalent in LINQ is `someList.Contains(field)`, eg `sizes.Contains(x.Sizes)`. EF will generate an `IN` clause from this

Comment: @Cid i meant with ( ) at the start and before &&

Comment: Isn't this the same as [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63663597/how-to-use-multiple-where-expressions-and-chain-them-together-with-and-and-or)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var sizes = new List<string>() {"Small", "Medium", "Large"};
var filteredList = listFromWebRequest.Where(x => sizes.Contains(x));
```

edit:
The following implementation below would be completely dynamic - the `filters` list can now be kept somewhere else, and be made static.

```
var queryParameters = new List<string>() {"Nike", "Tree", "Large"};

var sizes = new List<string>() {"Small", "Medium", "Large"};
var brands = new List<string>() {"Adidas", "Nike", "Puma"};
var filters = new List<List<string>>() {sizes, brands};

var filteredList = queryParameters.Where(x => filters.Any(y => y.Contains(x)));
```

Comment: Where is `listFromWebRequest` coming from? Also how does this actually address the OP question of filtering types *and* sizes?

Comment: The `listFromWebRequest`is the sizes array or types array that OP specified came from the QP - in other, words, from a webrequest.
This is now dynamic in the sense that if we wishes to add new sizes or types, he can add them to those lists - they can be static somewhere for all I care.
To make it even more dynamic, you could have a list of lists that you loop through inside the Where filter - this way you have a static list of lists somewhere, and you won't ever have to touch the implementation

Answer (score 0):

database.table.Where(e => sizes.Contains(e.Sizes))